# Regex and cPanel Account Filtering

Tags: regex, cpanel

after countless hours googling and trying to contact my webhost (with no positive results) I wanted to jsut 'throw my question out there' and get better expertise with my issue. I really do believe, that this will be helpful to a lot of people as well, stuck asking the same question!

Just to keep things short, we have hosted our email solution with a webhost using cPanel and I have a big requirement. Basically, I need an account level filter to block certain mail addresses from sending out to other mail servers. For example;

- lets say we use example.com
- `user1@example.com` can send mail to anyone, anywhere
- `user2.int@example.com` is only allowed to send mail to example.com address but not to any other address, for example gmail.com, yahoo.com, etc.
- Out of the options given to me at account level filtering, I thought the best to use is regex.
- I'm suspecting that EXIM (default mta for cpanel) uses PCRE like regex expressions, please correct if im wrong.
- The syntax i wrote and need help with is the following:

  `^(?!.+\@example\.com$).*$`

With this, all example.com addresses should not match and all other addresses should.

The testing tools I used is https://www.debuggex.com/

Guys, please help and let me know what I am doing wrong. cPanel is letting mail go through and is not blocking it.

Comment: Try something like this regex and see if it works `^(?![^@]*?@example\.com)`

Comment: thanks skamazin, can i trouble you just for teh breakdown of that syntax before I place an account level filter? Fairly a newbie to regex

Comment: Did that work properly? If so, I'll just post it as an answer and I'll explain it there

Comment: skamazin, no luck with the syntax, even though if you use an online tool to test syntax (which gives me the results i want), on cpanel its still allowing the mail go through

Comment: Try using a double back slash `\\.com`. Syntax is not standardize across all regexes, so I can only point you in the right direction. Try test my regex with your input data by clicking the link in my answer

Comment: cool, i did try it on the link u gave, unfortuantely in that the conditions example.com and gmail.com return the same results, "1 match foud" Ideally, addresses at example.com should return false whilst gmail addresses should return positive. Should i still try this on cpanel?

Comment: Edit your question and show some input (5-6 addresses). Tell me which addresses should match and which shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

The regex:

```
^(?![^@]*?@example\.com)
```

should do the trick

**How it works**

- `^`: Find the beginning of the string/line
- `(?!...)` Assert that it is impossible to find the following regex:

  - `[^@]*?` Match all the characters that are not an at symbol (`@`)
  - `@example\.com` Match the exact string `'@example\.com'`

For a more in-depth explanation see **[this](http://regex101.com/r/aN6xU4/1)**

Comment: thanks skamazin, no luck with the syntax, even though if you use an online tool to test syntax (which gives me the results i want), on cpanel its still allowing the mail go through

Comment: @DilDissanayake Unfortunately, I have no experience with `cPanel` so I can't help you with the code. Hopefully someone with `cPanel` knowledge can help you. Until then, I would just Google "cpanel regex" and pray that you get a good site to help you. Best of Luck!

Comment: many thanks for the attempt skamazin, lets keep fingers crossed, do check back here from time to time cuz if i find a solution, il post it back here

Comment: @DilDissanayake If you post some input data (email addresses) I can at least make a regex that will work. Though I can't guarantee that it will work with `cPanel`.

Comment: sure skamazin, using your syntax of ^(?![^@]*?@example\.com) I would like dil.int@example.com to be able to send to skamazin@example.com but not to dil@gmail.com or dil@yahoo.com, etc. To do this, i need the regex to negate @example.com addresses so in the filter, where i specify the "TO" address, i put your expression. So as a summary, anything@example.com should indicate a no match, where as other addresses such as gmail, yahoo etc gives me a match in either the online tool I gave or the one you gave. Hope this is not too complicated.

Comment: Just as an FYI, in my rule on cPanel, the "FROM" rule is working fine with a very simple regex statement of \.int@example\.com

Comment: one quick thing im trying to do, can you negate this for me .+\@example\.com just as simply as possible. I think I might be able to solve this

Comment: By negate, I'm assuming you mean something like assert that you can't find it ahead. That would be `(?!.+\@example\.com)`